# Using an Expression in a compiler-generated expression tree

Tags: c#, linq

I know I can create expression trees using:

1. Factory methods.
2. Compiler conversion of a lambda expression to an `Expression`.

For complicated expression trees I would prefer 2 because it is more concise.

Is it possible to refer to already constructed `Expressions` using this way?

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    public static Expression<Func<int, int>> Add(Expression expr)
    {
#if false
        // works
        ParameterExpression i = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Expression.Add(i, expr), i);
#else
        // compiler error, can I pass expr here somehow?
        return i => i + expr;
#endif
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<int, int> f = Add(Expression.Constant(42)).Compile();
        Console.WriteLine(f(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think all you need is to specify the type of expression in the add from Expression to Expression<int> since I think that's what is happening in the above example but it is inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix arbitrary `Expression` instances with compile-time expression trees. What you *can* do is construct a new expression tree with specific nodes replaced, so you can have `i => i + marker` and then construct a new tree with the `marker` node replaced by your runtime expression. This requires writing an appropriate `ExpressionVisitor`:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions {
  public static T AsPlaceholder<T>(this Expression expression) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
      "Expression contains placeholders."
    );
  }

  public static Expression FillPlaceholders(this Expression expression) {
    return new PlaceholderExpressionVisitor().Visit(expression);
  }
}

class PlaceholderExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
  protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) {
    if (
      node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(ExpressionExtensions) && 
      node.Method.Name == "AsPlaceholder"  // in C# 6, we would use nameof()
    ) {
      return Expression.Lambda<Func<Expression>>(node.Arguments[0]).Compile()();
    } else {
      return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
  }
}
```

`Add` now becomes:

```
public static Expression<Func<int, int>> Add(Expression expr) {
    Expression<Func<int, int>> add = i => i + expr.AsPlaceholder<int>();
    return (Expression<Func<int, int>>) add.FillPlaceholders();
}
```

The slightly cryptic expression

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<Expression>>(node.Arguments[0]).Compile()()
```

can be explained by observing that the compiler will capture the expression we're inserting in a closure, regardless of where it came from, so the argument of the method call is always a reference to this closure that we need to evaluate to get at the actual expression.

This scales to an arbitrary number of replacement expressions with a minimum of explicit typing.

Comment: I've revised this answer to go from a different way of using Servy's `ReplaceVisitor` to a novel approach where we use the expressions themselves as placeholders.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything out of the box, but you can build a tool yourself to provide this functionality.

You can write a method that accepts an expression that has two parameters, one "real" parameter and one parameter of some value that you want to substitute with the value of another expression.  You can then have an expression that resolves to that value and replace all instances of the parameter with the second expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> BuildExpression
    <TSource, TOther, TResult>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TOther, TResult>> function,
    Expression<Func<TOther>> innerExpression)
{
    var body = function.Body.Replace(function.Parameters[1], innerExpression.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(body, function.Parameters[0]);
}
```

You can use the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

You can then apply it to your case as follows:

```
public static Expression<Func<int, int>> Add(Expression<Func<int>> expr)
{
    return BuildExpression((int i, int n) => i + n, expr);
}
```

Comment: Nice. For some reason I had in mind that you needed to override all members of `ExpressionVisitor`, but of course just `.Visit()` will do. I'm sure something more generic could be devised for `BuildExpression`, though -- it's not very clear that it's replacing the second parameter with an expression, and scaling this to multiple replace values would likewise be a pain.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Genericising it to a greater degree is of course possible, but somewhat more work, yes, so for the sake of simplicity I limited the scope to only what's needed to solve this problem, so that it would remain understandable.

Comment: I updated my answer with a potential alternate way of using `ReplaceVisitor`. I think I'll keep looking for the Holy Grail for a while as an exercise. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert A fully generalized solution would be one or two hundred lines of code, potentially [much] more if you want something heavily optimized for general use, and explaining such a solution would add quite a bit of complexity, well beyond what an SO answer can fit.  It's certainly possible though.