# Custom Extension-Function to implement "IN" in c# (LINQ-2-Entities)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

For example:

.Contains(...) is supporten in Linq2Entities and is transformed to "IN" SQL-Expression.

I wan to rewrite this query:

```
var foundExntities = myDbContext.MyEntityes.Where(o => new List<int> {111, 222, 333).Contains(o.ID)).ToList()
```

in form like there:

```
var foundExntities = myDbContext.MyEntityes.Where(o => o.ID.In(111, 222, 33)).ToList()
```

How can I write correspondend custom **In(...)** Extension-Function?

Comment: I recommend you don't. Defining extension methods on `int` is very confusing when those leak into contexts where they can't be used (and writing them so they can be used everywhere doesn't seem worth it). Aside from that, I don't think you *can* -- the method would need to be recognized by the EF expression tree parsers and I don't think those have extension points. (Though I'm not familiar enough with EF itself to tell for sure.) I suppose you could wrap the `IQueryable` implementation, but even that seems far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: While it is possible using `params int[]` to declare variable number of integer arguments (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-add-custom-methods-for-linq-queries), I opposed to creating custom aggregate method like that in EF. It can be raise such problems like `LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize the method` since the custom method sometimes not directly translated to SQL query.

Comment: I only want to extract **good known for EF (LINQ-2-SQL) expression** to such macro-function. This function will only extend my query-tree.

Comment: "Your query tree" still has to be parsed by the same parser methods as all the others, and you can't change *those*, that's the problem. You can *rewrite* the expression tree so the existing EF parser recognizes it, but you have no hook for doing so -- the definition of `.Where()` is not under your control. (Unless you write it, and all the other methods that take a predicate, but that seems undesirable.)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, definition of `.Where(...)` is not under my control, BUT I can still create an function/method, which gets a two parameters - query and Lambda Func expression with some condition and injects this condition into this query.
So, on the main tree I can use my custom macro-extensions. Importan thing there - this extension must use only **_good known for EF (LINQ-2-SQL) expressions_**.
Now I check if it is possible to write some extensions for "internal" (between brackets) part of .Where(...).

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: That's possible (using `ExpressionVisitor`), but decidedly nontrivial. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27000371/4137916) for a start.) I also don't see how you would call it "naturally". If anyone forgets to transform the query (which would be very easy to do, because you can't make `.Where()` do it), it would simply fail at runtime.

Comment: Thanx for Link - looks like interresting

Answer (score 6):

> How can I write correspondend custom In(...) Extension-Function?

You can't without also writing a full fledged query provider which converts the expression tree by recognizing your custom extension methods and translating them accordingly (similar to [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) `AsExpandable()` implementation).

What you can do though is to create a custom `IQueryable<T>` extension method with the restriction that it could only be used with LINQ method syntax and only with root queryable operators:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, V>> valueSelector, params V[] values)
    {
        var condition = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { typeof(V) },
            Expression.Constant(values), valueSelector.Body);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition, valueSelector.Parameters);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

which is applicable to your sample as:

```
var foundEntities = myDbContext.MyEntityes.WhereIn(o => o.ID, 111, 222, 33).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Ivan!

Comment: Hi @Ivan Stoev, please correct me if I'm wrong but looks like T and V have to be the same type, so why specify 2 of them? Couldn't it just be like public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, T>> valueSelector, params T[] values) ? Thanks

Comment: @LeonardoSpina `V` is the type of a property of `T` represented by `Expression<Func<T, V>> valueSelector`. So in this example, `T` is `MyEntity`, `V` is `int` and we checking `int ID` property. It's similar to [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_OrderBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) where you have 2 types - source, key and key selector.